# Implementing a template-specific page initialize function

Tags: javascript, pug

Coming out of the dark ages and trying out Jade. Fun stuff so far.

I want to execute a JavaScript function when the template in question (in this case, index.jade) has loaded. If I were doing this in good 'ol HTML I might approach it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Initialize the app on document ready.
    $(initializeStuff);
</script>
```

I can see how to include an arbitrary js file in my template, but not how to actually call a function from it:

```
extend default

script(src="/js/default.js")

block content

  form(id="upload", class="dropzone", method="post", action="/upload")

  p.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pri tacimates salutatus forensibus ea. Sit ceteros hendrerit
    consequuntur an, dicta tibique eu vis. Habeo impetus comprehensam te nam, in sit feugait
    principes. Cibo possit oblique qui cu, aperiri vivendum sed ne. Minim repudiare ne cum,
    ex graeco quodsi ius.
```

In this case, I want to call "initStuff()" to fix up some options on the "dropzone" form, etc.

Can someone point me in the direct direction?  Thanks...

Comment: Why not to put `initStuff()` call at the end of that /js/default.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you have already can be translated to Jade like this (based on the [example on jade-lang.com](http://jade-lang.com/)):

```
script(type='text/javascript').
  // Initialize the app on document ready.
  $(initializeStuff);
```

Output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Initialize the app on document ready.
    $(initializeStuff);
</script>
```